Volatile(Temp) Tables in BQ
I am trying to find a way to create Volatile/Temp tables in BQ as we can do in Teradata. I tried begin/end and it worked but cant access the temp table via select * just after running it as getting error saying "Table must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)."
Please suggest, TIA
tried created temp table via create temp table [tablename] with begin/end, it created but cant access the table. I am planning to create 10+ temp tables, later union them and create a final schema table

BigQuery uses temporary tables to cache query results that aren't written to a permanent table. The tables are created in a special dataset and named randomly. You can also create temporary tables for your own use within multi-statement queries and sessions.
You can refer to a temporary table by name for the duration of the current multi-statement query. This includes temporary tables created by a procedure within the multi-statement query. You cannot share temporary tables. Temporary tables reside in hidden _script% datasets with randomly generated names. Listing datasets article describes how to list hidden datasets.
After a query finishes, the temporary table exists for up to 24 hours. To view table structure and data, go to the BigQuery console, click Personal history, and choose the query that created the temporary table. Then, in the Destination table row, click Temporary table.
You can check more information about temporary and permanent tables in the following documentation.

You can create a temporary table using
CREATE TEMP TABLE <tablename> ...

Here is the link to the SQL documentation.  From your question, it sounds like a reference error and not a table creation error.  In BigQuery, tables are identified by:
<project>.<dataset>.<table>

In your question, you didn't declare what you used as a table reference nor what you used as a query reference.  My suggestion is to explicitly declare at least the dataset and table name in your queries and don't assume defaults.  That way there will be unambiguous reference.

as I am trying to create the temp table, why do I have to mentioned the dataset/project name. If i mention that information then it will not be a temp table anymore, BQ will create that as a table in my storage.
I am trying to create 10 temp tables for various purpose and in the end want to union all to get a table in my schema.
I tried creating using BEGIN/END. then went to table details and got it's ID but it is changing everyday, in that case, I cant do automation to run the full code daily.
Please advice.
